# For h=liminf f(x+k) , show that h=0 almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I was given some exercises about real analysis, but I cannot solve it.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ be an integrable function. For any $k \in \mathbb{N},$ define $f_{k}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f_{k}(x)=f(x+k)$ and set $h(x)=\liminf _{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k}(x) .$ Show that $h=0$ almost everywhere

What I've tried is following :

Using Fatou's lemma, I can show that integral of h is finite since f is integrable.
Then, h(x)=h(x+n) for any integer n by definition of h. But I cannot proceed forward.

Please give me some advice!!

Comment: Have you tried using Fatou's Lemma to show that $\int h = 0$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have no idea how to show integral of h is 0 using Fatou lemma. I just showed that integral of h is finite using Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use Fatou's Lemma to prove that $\int h = 0$, which is equivalent to $h=0$ almost everywhere.

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ consider the function $g_n = \chi_{[0,n]}\cdot f$. Then, we have $g_n \to f$ and $|g_n|\leq |f|$, and by the Dominated Conveergence Theorem, we conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n = \int f.
$$
Then, notice that
$$
\int f = \int f_n + \int g_n,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N,
$$
consequently,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f - \int g_n = 0.
$$
Using Fatou's Lemma,
$$
\int h = \int \liminf_{k\to \infty} f_k \leq \liminf_{k\to\infty} \int f_k \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I got it.